# Send Image by xmppfrmaework

Tags: ios, objective-c, ejabberd, xmppframework

I have set up ejabberd server on localhost, then I registered an account on Adium by selecting XMPP (jabber) server on port 5222. After that I configured an account on mobile test app and sent messages between two users (Adium/test app) successfully. But I am facing an issue(no error messages in console) while sending image from my test app to Adium. It is not received on Adium.

```
NSData *dataF = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageName, 0.0);


NSString *imgStr = [dataF base64EncodedStringWithOptions: 0];


NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];

[body setStringValue:@"123"];


NSXMLElement *ImgAttachement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"attachment"];

[ImgAttachement setStringValue: imgStr];


NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];

[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];

[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:jid];

[message addChild:body];

[message addChild:ImgAttachement];


[self.xmppStream sendElement:message];
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We saw a similar issue in our ios app. I think you need to somehow add the two users as friends/contacts and make sure you have enabled mod_vcard_xupdate module in ejabberd config file. See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I couldn't find the config file please explain the path.

Comment: It should be in conf folder in the dir where ejabberd is installed (for us it is /opt/ejabberd)

Comment: In **conf** folder there are 4 files. I searched the **mod_vcard_xupdate** in ejabbered.yml and all but I couldn't find the module. Thanks

Comment: In that yml file you should have an entry for mod_vcard:[] and also one for mod_vcard_xupfate:[], if they are not add them. That is what I meant by enable module

Comment: I tried the way you suggested but somehow it didn't work. Kindly help me. Thanks.

Comment: Did u restart ejabberd? Are u using vcard related code in IOS? I am not a IOS person but I remember our IOS developer code some code using vcard extensions. Lastly test in adium first by making two friends/buddies with each other and make sure you both each other's avatars, before checking in IOS.